# Que son los sockets y como se usan en Python

Tags: python, socket, redes

Que son los sockets y como se usan en Python para poder pasar por ejemplo archivos?

** tuve que editar la pregunta ya que era un poco general al parecer, ignoren los comentarios antiguos a esta edición hecha a las 19:54hs **

Comment: Bienvenido BrodaCode a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Lamentablemente tu pregunta es muy amplia y basada en opiniones, el formato del sitio apunta a preguntas mucho más concretas. Te sugiero que arranques con algo básico que puedes resolver sin necesidad de librerías adicionales, un simple clientes/servidor sobre TCP/IP: https://rico-schmidt.name/pymotw-3/socket/tcp.html

Comment: Pero como funcionan?

Comment: Cuando creas un socket en python (o de cualquier otra forma). Depende del cliente y el servidor, estos dos se envían paquetes. Como dice @Patricio Moracho es un tema muy amplio, deberías empezar por un tutorial que trate los fundamentos básicos. Esto es una recomendación [link](https://www.studytonight.com/network-programming-in-python/) (esta en ingles).

Answer (score 1):

No sé bien como se abre un socket en python, pero los sockets son conceptos abstractos para compartir información entre dos computadoras o entre dos procesos en la misma computadora.

Esto que parece tan feo, es realmente sencillo. Suponete que yo tengo mi computadora que necesita compartir información con la tuya. La forma en la que "hablamos" entre mi computadora y la tuya es a través de un socket. Podrías pensarlo como un "archivo" que compartimos los dos, y en donde vamos escribiendo mensajes.

HTTP funciona con sockets: de hecho, una de las configuraciones que tienen todos los webservers es la cantidad de sockets simultáneos que se pueden abrir.

Si tenés linux, podés saber cuantos sockets puede abrir como máximo el sistema operativo con el siguiente comando:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
```

En mi caso, es el default, que son 32.000 aproximadamente. Eso quiere decir que si me pusiera un webserver, podría tener como mucho, 32.000 conexiones concurrentes. Si tuviera más, tendría que modificar ese máximo, o bien clusterizar.

Comment: Gracias por la información clara y sencilla :D